# Remove unwanted tags if its before text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code. `Variable` have a string. I want to remove `<img>` tag, `<a>` or `<br>` tag if its before any text.

```
var content='<div class="dir"><a href="/home"><img src="/img.png"/></a><p><br><a class="foo" href="/contact">This</a> is content</p></div>';
content.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g,"");
```

I've tried to remove `<img>` tag but it removes all of them, I just all unwanted tags ( and 
)to be removed before text. Secondly the `<a>` tag with `class foo` should not be remove because it has some text.

It returns:

```
<div class="dir"><a href="/home"></a><p><br><a class="foo" href='/contact'>This</a> is content</p></div>
```

In short I want to remove all images before text and all unwanted spaces by `br` and unwanted links.

Comment: [Mandatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @SterlingArcher I want to remove tags before text, not all of them.

Comment: if you can use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm understanding you correctly this is what you want to do.

```
<div><p><br><img><a class="foo" href="/contact">This</a> is content</p></div>
```

if class `foo` has any text in it then you want the content to be:

```
<div><p><a class="foo" href="/contact">This</a> is content</p></div>
```

no sibling `<br>`, `<img>`, or `<p>` tags.

If that is correct then this jquery solution could work if you are getting the `var content` from the DOM:

```
$('.foo').contents().each(function(){
  if(this.nodeType == 3){
    $(this).parent().siblings("br, img, p").remove();
  }
});
```

This will loop through the contents of all `foo` classes on the page...check to see if the nodeType is 3 (which is the value for a text node)...then get the siblings of the text node's parent that are `<br>`, `<img>`, or `<p>` tags tags and remove them.

[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/yehuvabifu/edit?html,js,output)

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is notoriously difficult to process with regular expressions.

It would be simpler and more reliable :

- to create a DOM fragment
- use jQuery to find the nodes you want to remove
- use `.outerHTML` to resynthesize the HTML (if necessary).

It's not 100% clear what the selection rules are but the general approach will look something like this :

```
var content = '<div class="dir"><a href="/home"><img src="/img.png"/></a><p><br><a class="foo" href="/contact">This</a> is content</p></div>';
var $content = $(content); // create unappended DOM fragment
var $allNodes = $content.find("*"); // all nodes inside the outer <div> wrapper
var $textNodes = $allNodes.contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3; // find text nodes
});
$allNodes.not($textNodes.parents()).remove(); // Remove all nodes that do not have a text node amongst their descendants.
$content.find("a").contents().unwrap(); // Unwrap the contents of any remaining <a> nodes.
var HTML = $content.get(0).outerHTML; // resynthesize HTML, with stuff removed
console.log(HTML);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w3hreyr1/

Comment: A good approach but I want to remove all unwanted tags before the text starts. Like
`<br>
Text starts here
<br>
`
Remove `<br>` above text.

Comment: @Anonymous0day, I haven't got a clue what DOMParser is. Suggest you write an answer.

Comment: @MohammedHâmzã, as I say, that's a general approach. You will need to work at it to get exactly what you want.

Comment: It can be the same approach you have but without jQuery !

Comment: Ah OK, so the same concept with a different lib - cool! I would be interested to see what a  DOMParser solution looks like.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 it is not a library ! [Code snippets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/HTML_to_DOM) or [parsing XML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML)

Comment: @Anonymous0day Interesting, but the fact it is IE10+ only for HTML can stop from using it in many projects. I suppose that's why the OP rejected the suggestion.